# Pause Rendering/Drawing CTreeCtrl (MFC)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

Is there a way to pause the rendering of a `CTreeCtrl` or its `CTreeView` during an expensive operation like expanding/collapsing all nodes in a tree? If there's no function for it like `PauseRendering(TRUE)` or something similar, would it be possible to maybe intercept the draw message and only forward it to the tree if my ExpandAll method wasn't being called?

Comment: Sounds like a job for threads.

Comment: Probably true, but I'm fairly new to C++ and entirely new to MFC, so I'm not sure that would be a good idea atm because I have a deadline for this thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`WM_SETREDRAW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message: when sent with `wParam` to `FALSE` it will prevent the window from receiving `WM_PAINT` messages; when sent with `wParam` to `TRUE` it will be set to normal.

Don't forget to manually repaint the window after you are done, because it is not done automatically:

```
RedrawWindow(hWnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_ERASE|RDW_FRAME|RDW_INVALIDATE|RDW_ALLCHILDREN);
```

Comment: Thank you! I surrounded the calls to my `ExpandAll` method with `Tree->SendMessage(WM_SETREDRAW, FALSE)` and `Tree->SendMessage(WM_SETREDRAW, TRUE)`, and it sped it up considerably. I will note that the `CWnd::RedrawWindow` method only takes 3 parameters when called from CTreeView (no hWND). `RedrawWindow(NULL, NULL, RDW_ERASE|RDW_FRAME|RDW_INVALIDATE)` worked for me. Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: My only problem now is that the vertical scrollbar for the tree view still draws during this whole process (and it looks jumpy because the `ExpandAll` method is recursive). But that's a UI issue, not a speed one.

Comment: I've had the same problem for a long time, having the vertical scrollbar appear and disappear even when SetRedraw is false, so I finally decided to do something about it! The solution is surprisingly simple (my class is derived directly from CTreeCtrl):

`CMyTreeCtrl::DisableRedraw()
{
    SetRedraw(FALSE);
    ModifyStyle(NULL, TVS_NOSCROLL);
}

CMyTreeCtrl::EnableRedraw()
{
    ModifyStyle(TVS_NOSCROLL, NULL);
    SetRedraw(TRUE);

    RedrawWindow( NULL, NULL, RDW_NOCHILDREN | RDW_UPDATENOW | RDW_INVALIDATE );
}`

Don't know why I didn't think of this years ago :-)

Comment: @JohnC You have done a great job, thx. I think it is a bug in Win32 TreeCtrl. After tested in my code, your approach also stop the control's border from refreshing (flashing).